# Loading comments from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I got an application that posts stories to Facebook (actions and objects are cutom).

Stories (when they are on facebook) can be commented, liked and shared.

My question is: is there a program way to load that stories' comments and likes (count at least)?

I tried an FQL like this, but it did not work:

```
select likes from comment where object_id=605173452834516
```

object_id was taken from [object browser](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser) (the object was shared in my timeline and I commented and liked it).

By the way, my app currently is in sandbox mode - can it be the reason I can not query the comments and likes?

Answer (score 1):

Can you give example of public post_id? So other people can access the content to test.

This example works fine:

```
select likes from comment where object_id='10151558994286749'
```

Original link: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151558994286749&set=a.53081056748.66806.6815841748&type=1

> If you scare is your app setting problem, you can test on this way:
>
> Copy user access token of your app, then paste/replace into **Access
>   token** field at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20likes%20from%20comment%20where%20object_id%3D'10151558994286749'